# Custom Layout for custom cell design on UICollectionViewController

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview

I want to design a page like this image for Ipad:
 [image: First Object is bigger than another one!]

I decide to implement it by UICollectionViewController, and I am going to use UICollectionViewController for the first time.
 I want to know, UICollectionViewController let me have various layout for cells? and how can I do that?

Comment: If you have just those views (not a repeating pattern of those views), then I don't think a collection view is the way to go -- you will have to subclass UICollectionViewFlowLayout to make an arrangement like that (assuming that each rectangle you're showing is a different cell). It would be easier to just add those as separate views to your controller's view.

Comment: @rdelmar there are unlimited cells so I think the collection view would be used! the first cell is bigger than another. thank you, I try to make a new Collection Layout...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have different layouts for cells.

In your UICollectionView, you will need to register the various cell classes that you are going to use:

```
[self registerClass:[Class1 class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Class1"];
[self registerClass:[Class2 class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Class2"];
```

Then in your datasource delegate:

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

//Whatever logic you will use to distinguish between the two classes

cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Class1" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//OR

cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Class2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: I do this, but does not work! it does not show any cell in view

Comment: Do you have the CollectionView working with a single cell class?  Also, I agree with rdelmar's comment about using static UIView's instead of a UICollectionView if those are the only views that you need.

Comment: I used nib file, so to use my nib file I must use [self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"MyCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"CELL"]; this shows my cells but It's not my approach! I think I need to define a custom layout to shows collection view like attached image!